# Issue using poetry to package python code (No file/folder found for package ...)

Tags: python, package, python-poetry

I have written a number of functions that help to ingest raw data from research device.

There's two groups of functions

Those that help to normalise timestamps

Those that actually read in/reshape the data

I have set the project up in a git repo, and there's two sub directories that contain each of the sub-sets
of functions

```
my_package

|- __init__.py
|- times

| |- __init__.py

| |- time_1.py

| |- time_2.py
|-reshaping

| |- __init__.py

| | - read_raw.py

| | - flatten.py

| - README.md

| - .gitattributes

| - .gitignore

| - licence
```

(sorry for the messy description of the folders I don't know how to make the nice folder diagrams you see on sites like this)

I'd like to use poetry to package this up, and I've seen that poetry is a good tool for doing this, but I when I go through the guides I can find online I get a set of errors and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I cd into the my_package folder and run `poetry init` and go through the process. The only dependency is pandas and the only dev dependency is jupyter. This produces the pyproject.toml file without error. Then I can run `poetry install` which produces the `poetry.lock` file and seems to install the dependencies without issue.

However, when I try to run `poetry build` I get the error

```
building my_package(0.1.0)

No file/folder found for package my_package
```

even though I'm *in the folder* `~\github\my_package`

I've tried finding the solution but a lot of the walkthroughs I've found aren't that helpful, and Friend_computer also hasn't been able to help.

Can anyone guide me on this? I'd really like to publish my first package.

Comment: can you use `poetry shell` to spawn a shell with your virtual environment? If so, can you execute your code inside this virtual env?

Comment: I can do that, but I still get the same error when trying to run `poetry build`